# Chosen js not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am trying to apply chosen select to all select elements in my form.

This is my JS file **script.js** which has the method defined to apply chosen

```
var script = (function(jQuery,window){


var applyChosen = function()
{
    jQuery('#saveForm :input').each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).is('select'))
    {
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        console.log('Applying chosen to id '+id);
        jQuery('#saveForm').find('#'+id).chosen({
            allow_single_deselect : true
        });
    }
    });
};

return {
 applyChosen : applyChosen  
};

})(jQuery,window);
```

This is my **HTML** file where I am calling the applyChosen() method to apply chosen on document ready to all select fields.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Chosen/chosen.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   script.applyChosen();
});
</script>


</head>
<body>
<form name="mainform" id="saveForm" action="file:///C:/">
                    <!--##GENERAL##-->


                        <div id="fromuser">
                            <table width="100%" id="userTable">
                            <tr><td class="title-cell" colspan="2"><p class="title">ERD Reporting</p></td></tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="label-cell">* Report Type :</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select id="repcode" name="repcode" class="validate[required] widthpx" data-prompt-position="inline">
                                            <option VALUE=""></option>
                                            <option VALUE="All Reports">All Reports</option>
                                            <option VALUE="004">004 - GMAC Branch 004</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="005">005 - GMAC Branch 005</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="007">007 - GMAC Branch 007</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="008">008 - GMAC Branch 008</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="010">010 - GMAC Branch 010</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="020">020 - GMAC Branch 020</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="021">021 - GMAC Branch 021</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="023">023 - GMAC Branch 023</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="029">029 - GMAC Branch 029</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="045">045 - GMAC Branch 045</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="061">061 - GMAC Branch 061</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="084">084 - GMAC Branch 084</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="085">085 - GMAC Branch 085</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="103">103 - GMAC Branch 103</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="123">123 - GMAC Branch 123</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="154">154 - GMAC Branch 154</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="201">201 - GMAC Branch 201</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="340">340 - GMAC Branch 340</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="ACK">ACK - ACH File Receipt Acknowledgement</Option>
                                            <option VALUE="ADJ">ADJ - Adjustment Report</Option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr id="accountRowID">
                                    <td class="label-cell" >* Account Number :</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="anumber" id="anumber" class="validate[required] widthpx" data-prompt-position="inline" onChange="script.selectChange(this);" title="You can select all accounts or enter your complete Account Number exactly as on site.Use comma [,] as a separator for multiple accounts">
                                            <option value=""></option>
                                            <option value="All Accounts">All Accounts</option>
                                            <option value="customAccountNumbers">Enter Account Number</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr id="PrinterNameRow">
                                    <td class="label-cell">Printer Name :</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="printtodefault" id="printtodefault" class="validate[required] widthpx" data-prompt-position="inline">
                                            <option value="false">--None--</option>
                                            <option value="true">--Default--</option>
                                            <option value="Send_To_One_Note_2013">Send To One Note 2013</option>
                                            <option value="Microsoft_XPS_Document_Writer">Microsoft XPS Document Writer</option>
                                            <option value="Microsoft_Print_to_PDF">Microsoft Print to PDF</option>
                                            <option value="Fax">Fax</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                           </table>
                        </div>


                </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code **works on all browsers except IE8**.
What changes should I make inorder to make it work on IE8+ browsers?

Comment: Did you get any error messages? First, I would change 'var script' to any other (non keyword).

Comment: I did't get any error message. The `console.log()` is also getting displayed but the `.chosen()` event is not working I guess.

Comment: You should try the jQuery calls. jQuery doesn't support IE8.

Comment: Found it......
`<!doctype html>` tag is compulsory for chosen.js to render in IE8


https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer from OP's comment:*

`<!doctype html>` tag is compulsory for `chosen.js` to render in `IE8`

Please refer [this](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/448) issue for resolution

Comment: Thanks Dave for posting this as an answer. I'll mark this answer and close this question.